# Flex ArrayCollection bubble item up or down by one position

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, arraycollection, bubble-sort

I have an ArrayCollection where I want to be able to bubble items up or down by one position.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining Robusto's two function calls into a single line :)

```
ac.addItemAt(ac.removeItemAt(n), n-1);
```

The `remove...` functions on the ArrayList return the item being removed, so you can easily reposition it in the collection.

Comment: Yeah, and this bombs if you don't check that n-1 is not out of bounds. Not only is this less readable and less instructive, but it's just a blatant rip-off of my answer. Keep your smiley.

Answer (score 5):

```
var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(yourArraySource);
ac.removeItemAt(n); // where n > 0 and n < ac.length
ac.addItemAt( item, n-1); // where n>0 ... you should test for that
```

etc.